# Numpy array from pandas frames can't be count vectorized due to "'float' object has no attribute 'lower'" error

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame that I am reading from a csv. It includes three columns, a subject line, and two numbers I am not using yet.

```
>>> input
                                                0         1  2
0             Stress Free Christmas Gift They'll Love  0.010574  8
```

I have converted the list of subjects to a numpy array, and I want to use count vectorizer for naive bayes. When I do that, I get the following error.

```
>>> cv=CountVectorizer()
>>> subjects=np.asarray(input[0])
>>> cv.fit_transform(subjects)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 780, in fit_transform
    vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents, self.fixed_vocabulary)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 715, in _count_vocab
    for feature in analyze(doc):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 229, in <lambda>
    tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 195, in <lambda>
    return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

These items should definitely all be strings. When I read the csv in with the csv library instead and created an array of that column, I didn't have any problems. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably those `nan`s arise from cases where the subject line was an empty string.  Just replace them with an empty string.

Comment: Thanks! I printed str.lower(subject) for all of the subjects, found where in the list it was giving me an error, and then found an N/A in the csv file. I don't know how to eliminate that record yet, but I'll be able to figure it out.